# knitr - Python engine cache option not working

Tags: python, r, knitr, reproducible-research

yihui gives an example of using the cache option for the different engines

https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/023-engine-python.Rmd

I can't seem to get it to work for python.

The following works

````
```{r,engine='python',cache=TRUE}
x=10
print x
```
````

But this doesn't work

````
```{r,engine='python',cache=TRUE}
x = 10
```

```{r,engine='python',cache=TRUE}
print x
```
````

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chunk option `cache` doesn't save all the variables defined in the block for languages other than `R`. It is, though, saving printed outputs, so if you compute something that takes a while, any results will not need to be re-computed. From the `knitr` website:

> Except `engine='R'` (default), all chunks are executed in separate
>   sessions, so the variables cannot be directly shared. If we want to
>   make use of objects created in previous chunks, we usually have to
>   write them to files (as side effects). For the bash engine, we can use
>   `Sys.setenv()` to export variables from R to bash (example).

It's possible to save a few values in the shell's environment, and retrieve those values from the other cells by reading the environment. This is the approach [Yihui took in the Polyglot example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/106-polyglot.Rmd). So, for Python, if you can format the value as a string and pass it to `sys.setenv()`, you could use that value in another cell (run as a separate Python session) by calling `sys.getenv()`.

Though, I am mildly confused about the approach taken with the `C` and `Fortran` engines. Those seem to have access to compiled functions in later chunks by [using some function called `.C()`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/090-engine-c.Rmd) or a [function called `.Fortran()`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/111-engine-fortran.Rmd). But it seems that Python does not have an equivalent.