# use tags in echo chunk option

Tags: tags, echo, knitr

I have an rmarkdown document that uses code chunks in various languages, including R, bash, and python.  For the R code chunks, context is preserved between chunks.  For the bash and python chunks it is not.  Hence, I have to replicate the set-up code in each python (for instance) chunk.  I prefer not to have the replicated stuff appear in the output, but I do want the stuff that's new in the code chunk to appear.  I'm using:

````
```{python someName, echo=19:32}
````

and similar to do this, and that works just fine.  The drawback is that if I add/subtract/rearrange, the absolute numbers (19 and 32 in the example) change.  This is a minor nuisance, but it would be nice if I could just tag the sections of code that I want to include/omit.  Is there some way to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, rather a workaround: Wrap the setup instructions in a function that you define once and that is called in the first lines of the chunks that need the re-setup. Thus you always have to simply exclude the first line, no matter what you change in the setup function.

Comment: Caching of python code chunks may not work. [Here's an issue from a while back with the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30175948/347567)