# Using python together with knitr

Tags: python, r, markdown, knitr

I would like to use python together with knitr.  However, python chunks seem to get evaluated separately, and variable definitions are lost between chunks.

How to solve this?

Minimal example:

#### test.pymd

````
---
title: "Minimal example"
---

With a print statement.

```{r hello}
x = 'Hello, Python World!'
print(x)
```

Without a print statement.

```{r world}
print(x)
```
````

#### test.md

````
---
title: "Minimal example"
---

With a print statement.


```python
x = 'Hello, Python World!'
print(x)
```

```
Hello, Python World!
```

Without a print statement.


```python
print(x)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```
````

#### knit2py.r

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

if(length(args) < 1) {
    message("Need arguments in the format: %.pymd [%.md]")
    q(status=1)
}

name <- substr(args[1],1,nchar(args[1])-4)

if(length(args) < 2) {
    args[2] <- paste0(name,".md")
}

library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(engine = 'python')

res <- try(knit(args[1], args[2]))

if(inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    message("Could not successfully knit RMD (or PYMD) to MD")
    q(status=1)
} else q()
```

And now run:

```
./knit2py.r test.pymd test.md
```

Comment: Have you already tried this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175948/knitr-python-engine-cache-option-not-working

Comment: This will be improved in the near future. For now, most non-R chunks are independent to each other, and variables don't persist.

Comment: @YihuiXie is there an update here? I thought I remembered something along these lines in one of the recent RStudio releases

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1440

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, indeed, knitr is currently not able to evaluate code stretching over multiple chunks for languages other than R. The solution is not to use knitr but to use pweave instead.  The modifications to the source file are minimal:

#### test.mdw

```
---
title: "Minimal example"
---

With a print statement.

<<>>=
x = 'Hello, Python World!'
print(x)
@

Without a print statement.

<<>>=
print(x)
@

The end.
```

And now run:

```
pweave -f pandoc test.mdw
```

There is a note on the [pweave](http://mpastell.com/pweave/)'s website that installation would fail with pip using python3. I had, though, no problems at all, when simply running:

```
pip install pweave
pip install markdown
```

Maybe, it is just an old note.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of two ways to run python code inside knittr chunks:

`````
---
title: "Works with python"
output: github_document
---

Does **knitr** work with Python? Use the chunk option `engine='python'`:

```{r engine='python'}
x = 'hello, python world!'
print(x)
print(x.split(' '))
```

Or use the syntax ```` ```{python} ````:

```{python}
x = 'hello, python world!'
print(x.split(' '))
```
`````

I got it from [knittr examples](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/023-engine-python.Rmd)

Answer (score 0):

Zen knit is alternative of RMarkdown for Python. Example of reports are at https://github.com/Zen-Reportz/zen_knit/tree/main/doc/example

It support creating report directly from python or .pyz file similar to .Rmd.

Current functionality
Python 3.7+ compatibility
Support for IPython magics and rich output.
Execute python code in the chunks and capture input and output to a report.
Use hidden code chunks, i.e. code is executed, but not printed in the output file.
Capture matplotlib graphics.
Evaluate inline code in documentation chunks marked using `{ }
Publish reports from Python scripts. Similar to R markdown.
Interactive Plots using plotly
integrate it in your process. It will fit your need rather than you need to adjust for tool.
custom CSS support (HTTP(s) and local file)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30722440)