# Using Python within R notebook

Tags: python, r, rnotebook

I have been using ipython (Jupyter) notebook for my tasks with R and Python. Recently, I explored R Notebook and I found the kind of functionalities I wish they were in Jupyter Notebook implemented in R Notebook. So, I want to switch to R Notebook. However, when using Python in R Notebook, I could not cache the python results and use output from one chunk in another chunk. Further, I am not able to generate the python plots inline. It gives me plots in a new window, not in the notebook itself. To just provide some reproducible code, the code below works fine and gives an output if you put it in a single chunk but if you divide it into a couple of chunks, you cannot call outputs from one chunk in another chunk. The figure also pops up in a new window.

````
```{python}
 # Import necessary modules
 from sklearn import datasets
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
 import numpy as np

 # Load the digits dataset: digits
 digits = datasets.load_digits()


 # Create feature and target arrays
 X = digits.data
 y = digits.target

# Split into training and test set
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2,    random_state = 42, stratify = y)

# Setup arrays to store train and test accuracies
 neighbors = np.arange(1, 9)
 train_accuracy = np.empty(len(neighbors))
 test_accuracy = np.empty(len(neighbors))

  # Loop over different values of k
 for i, k in enumerate(neighbors):
  # Setup a k-NN Classifier with k neighbors: knn
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)

    # Fit the classifier to the training data
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)

    #Compute accuracy on the training set
    train_accuracy[i] = knn.score(X_train, y_train)

    #Compute accuracy on the testing set
     test_accuracy[i] = knn.score(X_test, y_test)

  # Generate plot
 plt.title('k-NN: Varying Number of Neighbors')
 plt.plot(neighbors, test_accuracy, label = 'Testing Accuracy')
 plt.plot(neighbors, train_accuracy, label = 'Training Accuracy')
 plt.legend()
 plt.xlabel('Number of Neighbors')
 plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
 plt.show()
 ```
````

The plot below shows up in a new window. Not inline in the Notebook.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- I could not cache the python results and use output from one chunk in another chunk

  - It doesn't seem to be possible if language engine is other than R
  - see [knitr - Python engine cache option not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175948/knitr-python-engine-cache-option-not-working)
- I could not cache the python results and use output from one chunk in another chunk and I am not able to generate the python plots inline

  - Could you try knitron and share if it works?
  - knitron: knitr + IPython + matplotlib: https://github.com/fhirschmann/knitron

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to deal with this is using rPython. Using this library you can execute python code and get the results as R variables. Check this link to see an example:

https://github.com/rajshah4/tensorflow_shiny/blob/master/server.R

Answer (score 0):

Could be worth taking a look at the pweave python package.